# Moving the group of a checked item in a listview C#

Tags: c#, listview

I have a list view with two groups. I want it so that when I check an item it moves to the second group and when I uncheck it, it moves back to the first.

Here is the code I have tried so far:

```
private void lstServices_ItemChecked(Object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (ListViewItem item in lstServices.Items)
   {
     if (item.Checked)
     {
       item.Group = lstServices.Groups[1];
     }
     else
     {
       item.Group = lstServices.Groups[0];
     }
   }
}
```

Firstly I find it buggy. When I tick something it does tend to move to the second group, but when I untick it sometimes it goes back to the first group, sometimes they just wont untick at all and I can't work out why.

Secondly I think this is a messy way to do it, each time something is checked I'm checking the whole list and then moving accordingly. I'm assuming there is a way to address just the item I have just checked but I can't work out how!

Comment: First quick thing..while are you looping all the items?? Use e.Item and change the group only of the listitem firing the event.

Comment: That's what I'm looking to get rid of, the looping aspect of it, but I wasn't sure how. When you say use e.item, do you mean changing it like this:

private void lstServices_ItemChecked(Object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs **e.item**)?

That gives an error. Am I totally off the mark?

Comment: Don't change the event handler method, just add this :`ListViewItem item=e.Item; if (item.Checked)...`

Comment: I've added an answer so you see it complete

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be working much smoother now.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the loop, you must do something like this:

```
private void lstServices_ItemChecked(Object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
{
     ListViewItem item=e.Item;
     if (item.Checked)
     {
         item.Group = lstServices.Groups[1];
     }
     else
     {
         item.Group = lstServices.Groups[0];
     }
}
```

The [ItemCheckedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.itemcheckedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) variable `e` has one property, returning the ListViewItem that fired the event.

Comment: there is no e.Item is think

Comment: oh sorry. looked up ItemCheck event... yes, ItemChekeEventArgs do have Item property

Comment: Yes @UthistranS.,ItemChecked returns item in the ItemCheckedEventArgs :)